# AWK Compare two files and add new column from second file to first file if match

Tags: awk, printing, compare

I have problem I would like to compare two files. First files is reference:

```
ABCA4 INHR
AMT   INHR
BTK   ONKO1
PAP   ONKO2
```

Second file is for compare:

```
3  1:2 T ENG1  ABCA4 ff
3  1:2 T ENG1  ABCA4 gg
5  1:4 A ENG20 AMT   ll
6  1:5 G ENG12 BRB   ds
7  1:6 T ENG8  PAP   rg 
7  1:6 T ENG8  PAP   tt
```

And I want compare $1 from first file with $5 from second file and if there is match print between $5 and $6 in second file the $2 from first file:

```
    3  1:2 T ENG1  ABCA4 INHR  ff
    3  1:2 T ENG1  ABCA4 INHR  gg
    5  1:4 A ENG20 AMT   INHR  ll
    6  1:5 G ENG12 BRB     -   ds
    7  1:6 T ENG8  PAP   ONKO2 rg 
    7  1:6 T ENG8  PAP   ONKO2 tt
```

all columns are tab separated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you want the script output separated by tabs?

Comment: Yes I want, you did right too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$5=$5 "\t" (a[$5]?a[$5]:"-")}1' file1 file2
```

details:

```
NR==FNR {     # when the first file is processed
    a[$1]=$2  # store the second field in an array with the first field as key
    next      # jump to the next record
}
{
    $5=$5 "\t" (a[$5]?a[$5]:"-") # append a tab and the corresponding second
                                 # field from the first file if it exists or -
}
1 # true, display the line
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk with the same logic. And the output is separated by tabs.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if (a[$5]) $5=$5"\t"a[$5]; else $5=$5"\t""-"}1' file1 file2
```

Output, tab-delimited:

```
3       1:2     T       ENG1    ABCA4   INHR    ff
3       1:2     T       ENG1    ABCA4   INHR    gg
5       1:4     A       ENG20   AMT     INHR    ll
6       1:5     G       ENG12   BRB     -       ds
7       1:6     T       ENG8    PAP     ONKO2   rg
7       1:6     T       ENG8    PAP     ONKO2   tt
```